# Java 8 Streams - Map Multiple Object of same type to a list using streams

Tags: java, collections, lambda, java-8, java-stream

Is it possible to do the below mentioned steps using streams in a better way ?

```
Set<Long> memberIds = new HashSet<>();
marksDistribution.parallelStream().forEach(marksDistribution -> {
        memberIds.add(marksDistribution.getStudentId());
        memberIds.add(marksDistribution.getTeacherId());
      });
```

`instanceDistribution.getStudentId()` and `instanceDistribution.getTeacherId()` are both of type `Long`.

It might be possible that this kind of question is asked but I am not able to understand it. In simple yes or no. If yes/no, then how and bit explanation. **And if possible kindly, discuss the efficiency.**

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use the 3-args version of collect:

```
Set<Long> memberIds = 
    marksDistribution.parallelStream()
                     .collect(HashSet::new, 
                              (s, m) -> {
                                   s.add(m.getStudentId());
                                   s.add(m.getTeacherId());
                               }, Set::addAll);
```

Your current version may produce wrong results, since you are adding elements in parallel in a non-thread safe collection. So it may be possible that you have multiple times the same value in the set.

Comment: can you discuss the efficiency also compared to what I have done in question ?

Comment: @balboa_21 The problem is that what you have done is flawed. Before thinking about efficiency, you should think about correctness. That said, using `collect` is the canonical way to get what you want using streams.

Comment: c: Thanks you for the quick response. Ok, if supposedly,  I am not using parallelStream() ?.

Comment: @balboa_21 Still use `collect`. Otherwise you are left with a piece of code that won't work if someone decide to change in the future `.stream()` to `.parallelStream()`.

Comment: @balboa_21: if you are not using a parallel operation, you can use `forEach` directly on the Collection, i.e. without a Stream operation at all.

Answer (score 8):

Yes, you can use `flatMap` to map a single element of your `Stream` into a `Stream` of multiple elements, and then flatten them into a single `Stream` :

```
Set<Long> memberIds = 
    marksDistribution.stream()
                     .flatMap (marksDistribution -> Stream.of(marksDistribution.getStudentId(), marksDistribution.getTeacherId()))
                     .collect(Collectors.toSet());
```

Comment: can you discuss the efficiency also compared to what I have done in question ?

Comment: @Eran 1+ from me, still if u have jdk-9 you could use a flatMapping collector:  list.stream().collect(Collectors.flatMapping((MarksDistribution md) -> Stream.of(md.getStudentId(), md.getTeacherId()), Collectors.toSet()));

Comment: @Eugene Nice, I should probably try jdk-9 sometime soon.

Comment: @Eugene: like with all Stream operations, I would use the Collector counterpart only when necessary. You could express almost every Stream operation as a Collector-only operation, especially with Java 9, but it would be quiet hard to read…